How to fix the broken Wingdings font?
An application that I work with broke after the upgrade of the OS to Windows 10. Nothing else changed: the version of .NET, the C# project, the Visual Studio are still the same versions.
It displays Wingdings characters on one of its control, and it worked fine and continues to work fine under the old versions of Windows.
Under Windows 10, some but not all characters are replaced with rectangles. There is no rhyme or reason. It's like characters 100, 103 and 106 display, whereas 101, 102, 104, and 105 are corrupted. The codes are made up, for simplicity's sake.
How do we restore the normal operation?
I tried to take wingdings.ttf from an old system where the application correctly displays all characters, embed it as a resource in the application, and load it instead of using the system font, but nothing changed.

Is the font installed in the target machine? If not, you can FOD it. Or you can ship it with your app and configure your installer to add it if needed. Or you can load it from the resources to use it privately. Or Wingdings character set and equivalent Unicode characters.

All of that is covered in the question.

Can you provide a minimal code snippet to show how the font is being used?

Nothing is covered in your question but a story that we can't reproduce and test. See [mre]

@PeterConstable The button's Font family property is set to Wingdings. There is no code behind. Some of the characters are corrupt under W10, which were not corrupt under the previous versions.

@BusterZo "Some of the characters are corrupt... " Can you provide a screenshot?
